# Stop audio after X seconds in js

Tags: javascript, audio

I do a little car game in 3D. For example, I want when the player, press up to speed, he has  the sound start at first and after speed. But the start only one time and speed in a loop.
My HTML:

```
<audio preload="auto" id="start"><source src="sounds/start.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<audio preload="auto" id="speed"><source src="sounds/speed.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
```

I have tried this thing in JS, but did not work:

```
document.getElementById('start').play();
setTimeout(document.getElementById('speed').play(),2000);
setTimeout(document.getElementById('start').pause(),2000);
```

How can I do ?
Thanks

Comment: this `document.getElementById('speed').play()` will invoked immediately, will not wait for 2 seconds.

Comment: Yes, but how to do for, play start, when finish, play speed in loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap your calls in an anonymous function so that they aren't immediately invoked, for example:

```
var player = document.getElementById('player');
setTimeout(function(){
    player.play();

    setTimeout(function(){
        player.pause();
        player.currentTime = 0;
    }, 2000);
}, 1000);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fyfRd/

To stop the file, you need to pause and reset the currentTime to 0

Comment: @Vineet I'm not sure, it's possible the mobile browser doesn't support the `pause` method or the `currentTime` property. I would check something like [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api)

Comment: @RobM. Should I go with this API ?